# FATAL: Could not find component we just installed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008, registration, com+

I have to do a modification on an old COM+ app written in C# 2.0. But when I try to register the DLL on a windows server 2008 machine with 'regsvcs excelserver.dll', I get the error:

```
  The following installation error occurred: 
  1: FATAL: Could not find component 'Excelserver.CExcelManager' we just installed
```

I tried to run in as admin, and turned off UAC, but it doesn't make a difference.

If I try it on a windows 7 or windows server 2003 machine, it works.

Any ideas why this doesn't work on a windows server 2008 machine? It seems I don't find any additional logging in the event log.

Thanks,
L

Comment: Could the difference be x86/x64?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to register using the 64-bit version of regsvcs instead of the 32-bit version.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Had to run regsvcs from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319, instead of the ...\Framework\... path that was used by default (in my PATH)